# PHP - IRC "QUIT" not working properly

Tags: sockets, irc

**CHANGE:**
I have determined the problem has nothing to do with the coding. However the problem stays still, as this appears to be caused by IRC, I'm still in search of the reason.

The server I'm connecting uses two kinds of PING requests:

One is asked upon connecting to server, and it's in format of alpha-numeric values of 8 characters.

Example: `PING :EA0E9275.`

And another one is after the server sends out MOTD, joins channels, completes "End of /NAMES list". Then after "n delay" server sends me a ping request with current connected host as it's value.

Example: `PING :irc.ams.nl.euirc.net`

If I send the command "QUIT :Quit Message" before I reply the host PING request, server ignores the QUIT message, and instead, it quits with a server-filled status message similiar to "Client Exited" message.

Example: `ERROR :Closing Link: Nick[IP.ADD.RE.SS] (Life is too short...)`

However if I send the same command after responding to host PING request, my QUIT gets processed as it should.

Example: `ERROR :Closing Link: Nick[IP.ADD.RE.SS] (Quit: Quit Message)`

I've checked in the RFC, and found this on QUIT section:

*If, for some other reason, a client connection is closed without  the client  issuing  a  QUIT  command  (e.g.  client  dies and EOF occurs on socket), the server is required to fill in the quit  message  with some sort  of  message  reflecting the nature of the event which caused it to happen.*

Also, if still in need to see the partial code I'm using to accomplish this, [you can check it here](http://pastebin.com/2EZigTUY). However, this is a common issue with mIRC the IRC client.

**Basic scheme**

- Connecting to server...

  - Connected!
  - Server waiting NICK/USER info...
  - Server received NICK/USER info, waiting for alphanumeric PING reply...

    - Server received alphanumeric PING reply, sending MOTD.
    - End of MOTD, sending JOIN to join channels...
    - Joined to channels, NAMES list for channels have been requested.
    - End of NAMES list.
  - Receiving active channel(s)/server data.

    - If sent QUIT command, server will ignore the usual QUIT, and will send "Closing Link" by server default as status quit(Life is too short...).
  - Server is doing an alive-check, received host PING(irc.ams.nl.euirc.net), server is waiting reply...

    - Sent server the reply.
    - If sent QUIT command, server will process QUIT command as user-level, the usual way, and will send "Closing Link" by user-specified message or empty.((QUIT: User Message) or (QUIT: ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's review your code for a bit:

1. When I made my IRC bot, I `explode()`ed the string from the server into words (splitting by space), you can then refer to words:

   ```
   if ($words[0] == "PING") { reply("PONG :" . $words[1]); }
   ```
2. Always `PONG` immediately after `PING`, and reply with the same message as the server.

If the second is fulfilled, you should never have that problem of the server waiting a PING, because you'll immediately answer. A client is expected to honor the PING PONG commands from the server, otherwise the server would think of it as offline (yes, even if you send anything else, the server expects PONG).

Comment: The code example I gave was overly-simplified, considering the one I have, it would just complicate things so I just put it for a reference. Also this occurs on any client. Second is, I think I'm misunderstood. What I try to accomplish is giving out a QUIT message, but that doesn't happen until server sends me the first alive-check after the one upon connection, and after I respond to it, everything works as cool. And yes, my code still does an immediate response to PING requests, I have no problems of disconnection.

Comment: Wait, so you're trying to QUIT before the first PING the server sends you, but it won't let you?

Comment: Updated the question with the basic scheme, it's too much to explain by words.

Comment: @TheDeadLike: Does the bad "close link" occurs immediately after sending the QUIT request? Or does the server simply ignores it and sends dies on its own a while later?

Comment: Immediately after. It simply receives the user-request of QUIT but doesn't just parse it that way, at least that's what it appears.

Comment: @TheDeadLike: Sounds like a problem with the IRC server. I can't reproduce it at my localhost.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll ask around in the IRC server.